# How do I use Jmeter to fire thousands of api requests at concurrently?

Tags: api, jmeter, performance-testing

I have a Thread Group with 200 threads. I need to send out 200,000 api requests (with different HTTP request paths) concurrently. Does any of the Jmeter timer can accomplish this? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Do you really mean 200,000 concurrent requests (i.e. at the exact same time)? If so, in JMeter you will need 200,000 threads...

Comment: See https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/what%E2%80%99s-the-max-number-of-users-you-can-test-on-jmeter

Answer (score 0):

Your use case is not very clear, in order to send 200 000 concurrent requests you need the same amount of threads (virtual users) under [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group). Once done you can ensure that they are being executed at exactly the same moment in time by adding [Synchronising Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Synchronizing_Timer).

HTTP Request paths can be parameterised using i.e. [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config).

---

There are also [Parallel Controller](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/parallel/Parallel.md#parallel-controller) and [Parallel Sampler](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/parallel/Parallel.md#parallel-sampler) plugins which you can consider as an alternative, you can install them using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

[image: JMeter Parallel Controller]

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me. I’m trying to simulate 200 virtual users (treads), each sending 1000 requests with millisecond apart. Is there any way that I can do this on Jmeter? Or I need to set up as many treads as the requests? Thanks for your help.